# Why does "find . -name somedir -exec rm -r {} \;" exit nonzero whenever it successfully deletes a directory?

Tags: bash

I want to find a folder in a known folder but with unknown exact path, thus I must use find. When I find it, I use -exec to remove it, but I cannot evaluate if this has succeeded. Behavior somewhat confuses me; if I don't find the folder, I get return code 0:

```
>find . -name "testuuu" -exec rm -r {} \;
find: ‘./.docker’: Permission denied
>echo $?
0
```

But when I do find the folder and manage to delete it, it returns error code 1:

```
> find . -name "test" -exec rm -r {} \;
find: ‘./.docker’: Permission denied
find: ‘./test’: No such file or directory
> echo $?
1
```

Is this expected behavior? Why?
Further, how can I get return code of "rm" and not "find" and thus evaluate if the folder was deleted?

Comment: Using `-exec rm -r ...` will not necessarily result in just one return code, so you should think about a different approach, probably one involving a script. You might find [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392993) to a similar question on *Unix & Linux* useful.

Comment: From `man find`: "find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur. This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely on the correctness of the results of find."

Comment: I don't see why an error occurred here, though. The file was found and deleted successfully.

Comment: ...and then `find` failed, when trying to recurse into the directory after it no longer existed. You need to tell it to change its order-of-operations (to take actions on directories only after operating on their children) if you don't want that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-depth` option to order a depth-first traversal -- that way `find` doesn't try to find things *under* your directory after the directory has already been deleted (an operation which, by nature, will always fail).

```
find . -depth -name "test" -exec rm -r -- '{}' \;
```

This option is also turned on by default when you use the `-delete` action in GNU `find` to delete content.

---

By the way -- if there are lots of `test` directories, you could get better performance by making that `-exec rm -r -- {} +` (which passes each copy of `rm` as many filenames as will fit on its command line) instead of `-exec rm -r -- {} \;` (which starts a new copy of `rm` for each `test` that is found), at the expense of no longer collecting individual error codes.